# Change formula to value if not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I need to change a cell to a value if it becomes not blank, so that I can reduce the amount of calculations that are running.

This is what i tried but it isn't working. I get a missing argument ) error:

If my formula, for example, in cell D is `=IF(c2="Bike","")`
once the cell says Bike, the word bike will become a value, but as long as it is blank, the formula will continue to run.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var value = e.range.getValue();
    if (e.range.getColumn() === 4 && ~e.range.getFormula().toUpperCase().indexOf("=IF(c2="Bike","")(") && value) {
    e.range.setValue(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  var value = e.range.getValue(); 
  if (e.range.columnStart == 4 && ~e.range.getFormula().toUpperCase().indexOf('=IF(c2="Bike","")') && e.value) { 
    e.source.toast("Flag1");
    e.range.setValue(e.value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get an error anymore, but it is not working. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IP8f7oOSY3zT0fYtMUkToQ0Tz5mLqtMRRi9Pt9lN3t0/edit?usp=sharing

function onEdit(e) {
  var value = e.range.getValue(); 
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && ~e.range.getFormula().toUpperCase().indexOf('=IF(A2="Bike","Bike","")') && e.value) { 
    e.range.setValue(e.value); 
    }
}

Comment: is it getting to this line `e.range.setValue(e.value); `

Comment: It says this: 
6:49:55 PM Notice Execution started
6:49:55 PM Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range') onEdit @ Code.gs:2

When i edit the cell a2, the formula in b2 is still there My understanding of script is very bad, sorry if this is not what you were asking.

Comment: Sounds like you are run the script from the editor without supplying the event object.  That won't work.  Just editor the sheet and use Logger.log() or e.source.toast()